# Loop through $_GET and $_POST in one go?

Tags: php, arrays

is there a way to dynamically access `$_GET` and `$_POST` in one go? IE, something like:

```
$do = array('GET', 'POST');

foreach($do AS $type) {
    foreach (${'_'.type} AS $var=>$val) {
         ... # logic
    }
}
```

I understand that there is `$_REQUEST`, but that doesn't tell me source (get or post) and that there are deprecated `HTTP_GET_VARS` and `HTTP_POST_VARS`, but those are deprecated.

Clearly, I can just loop individually. The reason why I'm trying to avoid this is that the logic is a little lengthy but also identical. It would be ideal to not have to have a copy of this logic and open myself up to mistakes.

Or am I completely thinking about this the wrong way and there is some other recommended approach?

Thanks!

---

#### Thank you

Thank you for the great feedback everyone. I think @deceze answers the question most objectively, but @charlee (and later deceze as well) alludes to a better solution.

In the end, I created a function with logic and then placed that in my foreach, as such:

```
foreach($_GET AS $var => $val) {
    $_GET[$var] = func($val);
}
```

I do end up with two foreach()'s, but I appreciate the legibility and increased usability. Thank you again everyone!

Comment: $do = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

:)

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419175/why-would-you-merge-get-and-post-in-php

Comment: I wouldn't overwrite $_REQUEST, but merging the two collections together at the start is a good approach..

Comment: Yeah, I just changed it. Didn't sound right to me as well. :-P

Comment: A similar question regarding this topic can be found here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651696/can-i-post-and-get-to-the-same-php-page

Comment: array_merge would also be bad because it would risk overwriting any existing variables

Comment: @Zanderwar It would be 'bad' only if such is not desired/expected. For a case like POST/GET I've never encountered a case where they were 'additive'. But it is still a difference of note.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (array('get' => $_GET, 'post' => $_POST) as $type => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: While a little bit better, the nested loops still feels "off' wrt the intended goal (as I am reading it, and it changes the shadowing a bit from a merge-first approach).

Comment: The intended goal seems to be to not have to repeat the code within the inner loop and apply it to both arrays. In this regard writing a function would indeed make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you do care about the source I suggest you loop individually. Its not safe to mash $_POST with $_GET because it would be much easier for hacker to pass data thru GET which is supposed to be POST.

Long logic can always be extracted to a function so you won't have a copy of this logic.

Comment: I'd like to see a clarification on that hacker part. GET is not any easier to spoof than POST, they're both trivial. Only in certain scenarios where you're trying to trick a third party is it easier to trick them into accessing a URL via GET than via POST. In the end neither is "safer" than the other though at all.

Comment: You are right. If you mix GET and POST I can make a url to trick the admin user to click it, like '/admin/delete-post.php?id=100'. This won't happen if `id` param is passed through POST. Yes I could make a form to submit the data, but this can be protected by CSRF.

Comment: Well, it would also be protected if the server properly checked whether the request is a GET or POST...

Answer (score 1):

Merge your arrays with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$_GET  = array('one' => 'foo', 'two' => 'bar');
$_POST = array('three' => 'foo', 'four' => 'bar');

$merged = array('_GET' => $_GET, '_POST' => $_POST);

foreach($merged AS $type => $array) {
    foreach ($array AS $var => $val) {
        echo "[{$type}] {$var}: {$val}" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
[_GET] one: foo
[_GET] two: bar
[_POST] three: foo
[_POST] four: bar
```

And yes, you shouldn't use `$_REQUEST`, [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12435518/1828051)

> it combines COOKIE as well as GET and POST, and the COOKIE data always takes precedence creating the possibility for dangerous "sticky" variables.

Comment: DO NOT use `array_merge` *for this*, as you will overwrite any existing values

Comment: That's right. So I merge them into a new array - see updated answer.

Comment: @Zanderwar In 'most' cases I'd argue that is the correct behavior. However, it is a difference to point out.

Answer (score 0):

If the logic is identical, you can try using a function. Put your entire code in the function and pass the array that you want to loop through i.e. $_GET or $_POST. If you want to know the source as to whether it is GET or POST, you can try concatenation.

It would help to know what sort of an output you want.